# How to get image url from s3.amazonaws.com after PUT-request?

Tags: react-native, amazon-s3

I'm trying to deal with uploading to s3.amazonaws.com.

I wrote two callbacks:

1. To get url from my backend for uploading .
2. To PUT my image on s3 with 'upload url' from 1st callback.

But I can't recive url for my uploaded image from s3. After PUT request I got an empty response.

I have this code:

```
// callback for getting upload url from my backend - works OK
const getPresignedUrl = useCallback(
  async (imageName: string) => {
    const configurationObject = {
      method: 'get',
      url: getUploadUrl(imageName, uploadImageCategory.AVATARS),
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
      },
    };
    const {data} = await axios(configurationObject);
    return data;
  },
  [getUploadUrl, token],
);

// function to get image body from uri - also OK
const getBlob = async (fileUri: string) => {
  const resp = await fetch(fileUri);
  const imageBody = await resp.blob();
  return imageBody;
};

// callback that puts my image to s3 server - seems like it's OK
const uploadUsingPresignedUrl = useCallback(
  async (preSignedUrl: string) => {
    const imageBody = await getBlob(uri);

    const configurationObject = {
      method: 'PUT',
      url: preSignedUrl,
      data: {
        body: imageBody,
      },
    };

    const {data} = await axios(configurationObject);
    return data;
  },
  [uri],
);
```

Further in the code I call these functions:

```
const onUploadImage = useCallback(async () => {
  const imageName = getImageName(uri); //just util for getting right image name

  const presignedUrl = await getPresignedUrl(imageName);
  console.log('presignedUrl', presignedUrl); // I see generated URL in response

  const putImageOnAws = await uploadUsingPresignedUrl(presignedUrl);
  console.log('putImageOnAws', putImageOnAws); // Response is empty

}, [getImageName, getPresignedUrl, uploadUsingPresignedUrl, uri]);

useEffect(() => {
  if (uri) {
    setAvatar(uri);
    onUploadImage()
      .then()
      .catch(err => console.log('err: ', err));
  }
}, [onUploadImage, uri]);
```

So when I call putImageOnAws I get empty response. I though there is should be a link to my uploaded image...

So my question is - How can I get url for my image uploaded on s3?

Comment: The backend will need to provide the presigned URL to access the uploaded data, assuming it's not public.

Answer (score 0):

There will be no special data in the url for the file after uploading, that you don't already possess.
When you request the pre-signed url, you already specify the file key(path) and file name.
So using these details you can construct the file url yourself.
It actually depends on your use-case. If your s3 bucket is public by exposed via a cloudfront distribution, your file url looks like this,

```
https://<your-cloudfront-url>/<your-file-key-or-path>/<your-file-name-with-extension>
```

Please add more details on the configuration of the s3 bucket for your specific scenario.

Comment: Unfortunatelly I cannot tell you more details, because I have no access to backend. I have just an api to make a pre-signed URL. That's all...

Comment: Do you have access to the function "getUploadUrl", can you add it to the question?

Comment: I figured out everithing. Needed link in my case is pre-signed url without query params. Thank you!